# Dialogflow or Firebase slow Execution

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, gcloud

My dialogflow project has encountered the following error message that I have been unable to resolve. Has anyone encountered such an issue and aware of how to resolve this?

```
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Warning, estimating Firebase 
Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. 
Initializing firebase-admin may 
fail
```

I am thinking that there may be an issue with my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.9.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.2.0",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning message is only that - a warning. It does not mean there is a problem.

If you are not using `firebase-admin` calls, then you have nothing to worry about.

If you *are* using `firebase-admin`, then you just need to be sure that the environment is referencing the project you expect.

*Update*

The "slow execution" is likely due to the Cloud Function cold starting - the environment had been shut down or otherwise wasn't running, so it needs to initialize and setup the environment. On subsequent calls, within a reasonable time, it should already be running and you won't experience the slowdown.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem it causes is that it slows the application by 4 seconds, affecting the overall user experience. I was hoping to address the problem so that the execution time would be more acceptable.